# Manage multiple sites in one WebStorm project

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm on a project where there is one parent directory with three web sites. Each site has its own package.json and node_modules.

```
- SiteNetwork (git repo, some shared resources)
    - Site 1 (server.js, node_modules, etc.)
    - Site 2 (server.js, node_modules, etc.)
    - Site 3 (server.js, node_modules, etc.)
```

I would like to set up a shortcut to run `npm install` in each of these three sub-directories (individually). By default, the "Run npm install" action runs at the top level (a fair enough assumption).

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this using the built in tooling. Have you tried treating each site subdirectory as a separate project?

Comment: I've considered that, but since I'm using WebStorm for certain git tasks, I wanted to have the project = git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the Macros feature under the Edit menu. Once you have a macro you are happy with, you can make it a shortcut by adding a keymap.

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 1):

Calling `npm install` directly for a subdirectory is [not possible](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974).

But you can still use this as your command:

```
cd site1 && npm install
```

I couldn't reproduce your `Run npm install` issue. I created a subdirectory, added a `package.json`, selected `Run npm install` and it installed the dependencies of this exact `package.json` file into the subdirectory.

Comment: OK cool, good to have a definitive answer. My issue is I have three sub-directories each with a package.json. I have no package.json in the parent directory.